# memory issue in Java Eclipse while generating Data validation report using XSSF

Tags: java, excel, oracle, xssf

I'm doing automation tool for ETL testing. It will extract data from an Oracle database and paste in Microsoft Excel and compare source-target based on the key columns.

While generating report, if the records exceeds 8000 it hits an exception:

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError:
>   Java heap space

Have also increased the Heap memory size to `-Xmx1524m` which didn't work. If i increase it more than `1524m`, Eclipse is not opening.

Comment: Run your program with VM argus : 

-Xms1024m -Xmx2048m

Comment: You can do it by right click Run Configuration  in your main class : select tab  - Arguments  , paste  this  :  -Xms1024m -Xmx2048m  in bottom panel of VM arguments

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to deal with "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space" error (64MB heap size)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37335/how-to-deal-with-java-lang-outofmemoryerror-java-heap-space-error-64mb-heap)